# Optional section was not defined error in nested layout pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net5

I have a *_Layout.cshtml* file that contains the following line.

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

And then I have a *StorageLayout.cshtml* file that specifies *_Layout.cshtml* as the layout file. *StorageLayout.cshtml* defines the `MainMenu` section and contains `@RenderBody()`.

But then my page that uses *StorageLayout.cshtml* as the layout file gives me an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Pages/Shared/_StorageLayout.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").

I'm not sure I understand this. The `Scripts` section is explicitly not required, so why is it an error? And, for that matter, what would be the correct way to implement this section in nested layout files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`required` is set to false, which means the section is optional.If the section is not optional, every content page that references the layout page must use the `@section` directive to define the section and provide content:-

```
@section Scripts{
    // content here
}
```

In some cases, you might want to make a section optional, but you want to provide some default content in the event that the content page didn't provide anything for the section. You can use the `IsSectionDefined` method for this:-

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("OptionalSection"))
{
    @RenderSection("OptionalSection")
}
else
{
    // default content
}
```

Any sections defined in the master layout should also be redefined in child layouts:-

_MasterLayout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("scripts", required:false)
    </body>
</html>
```

_ChildLayout.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "/_MasterLayout";
}
<div class="main-content-two-col">
@RenderBody()
</div>
@section scripts {
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
}
```

I think this would help resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but as I explained in my question, *Layout.cshtml* *does* include `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`. Also, as explained, `required` is set to `false`.

Comment: @JonathanWood I have seen that already. Actually, I was trying to clarify that.i think you are missing ```@section scripts {
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
}```in your StorageLayout.cshtml.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to test that. I just got kind of stopped with the first sentence in your answer because that was clearly not related to my issue.

Comment: @JonathanWood for that now I updated my answer by removing ```_Layout.cshtml``` things.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Neither of the pages has a RenderSection... one of them works and one of them doesn't. Downvote.